Is accepting gifts/food from non Muslims on occasions of their festivals a form of condoning their false beliefs?
After years of personal research on this matter, I've found that most scholars conclude that it is not allowed to accept gifts from non Muslims on their festivals as this entails supporting and condoning their false beliefs. However, I also found some differing scholarly opinion, as follows;
{Abu Qabus reported: A woman asked Aisha, “We have a nurse among the Magians and they give us gifts on their festivals.” Aisha said:
أَمَّا مَا ذُبِحَ لِذَلِكَ الْيَوْمِ فَلا تَأْكُلُوا وَلَكِنْ كُلُوا مِنْ أَشْجَارِهِمْ
As for the meat they have slaughtered, then do not eat it. Rather, you may eat from the fruit of their trees.
Source: Muṣannaf Ibn Abī Shaybah 31986
Abu Barza reported: He had neighbors among the Magians who would give him gifts during their new year celebration and festivals. Abu Barza would say:
مَا كَانَ مِنْ فَاكِهَةٍ فَكُلُوهُ وَمَا كَانَ مِنْ غَيْرِ ذَلِكَ فَرُدُّوهُ
Whatever they give you of fruits, then eat it. Whatever they give you besides that, then return it.
Source: Muṣannaf Ibn Abī Shaybah 23773
Ibn Taymiyyah comments on these traditions, saying:
فهذا كله يدل على أنه لا تأثير للعيد في المنع من قبول هديتهم بل حكمها في العيد وغيره سواء لأنه ليس في ذلك إعانة لهم على شعائر كفرهم
These narrations demonstrate that non-Muslim festivals do not prevent Muslims from accepting their gifts. Rather, the rule during the festival is the same as other times since it does not involve support for their rituals of unbelief.
Source: Iqtiḍāʼ al-Ṣirāṭ al-Mustaqīm 250
There's also an Hadith reported from Ali on the occasion of nayruz}
My questions are:

can someone please provide the authenticity/grade of these hadiths (by abu qaboos and abu barza)?

what do other scholars who are against accepting gifts (like al albani, bn baz, salih al fawzan etc., may Allah have mercy on them all) say about these hadiths since I'm sure they are aware of their existence.


Thank you.
